# Install SQLServer 2000 on Windows 10

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2000

I need to install SQL Server MSDE 2000 SP4 on Windows 10.

I have other machines that run Windows 7 and 8.1 and SQL Server MSDE 2000 works fine (with merge replication configured too).

Now I testing the same scenario with Windows 10, but setup is closing unexpectedly during installation.

I know that this version is very old, but is there a workaround to install it on Windows 10?